# Do Not See when right Clicking "Manage npm modules"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm

I am following along with Shawn Wildermuth's [Node.js for .NET Developers](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/nodejs-dotnet-developers). I have already install NodeJS Tools for Visual Studio from nodejstools.codeplex.com.

Everything appears to have installed properly, I have just created a "NodeJS Blank Website".

However, when Shaun says to right click the NPM node in the solution and choose "Manage NPM Modules", I do not have it.

[image]

**I circumvented the problem by doing an install from NodeJS command prompt directly but I sure would like to know why Visual Studio is ever changing and never consistent. I  need a new & better IDE.**

Help anyone?

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe it was replaced by 'install new Npm package'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem, and according to the Error message window, PATH in Environment Variable  was not set to the location to nodejs folder. After I changed nodejs folder location to C:/Program Files/nodejs, right click and "Install new npm packages..." worked well to install Express. Hoping this would help for you too.

Comment: I tried a few variants of adding the nodejs folder to the path but have been unable to get it to work. Where are you adding the path to the Environment Variable, and what is the exact path you are using?

Comment: Please provide details of how and where you update the PATH variable.